# How to use Unpivot Using SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to use unpivot function but i am not sure if this is the right method because i am not getting the desired results.  Here is what i have as an example:

```
CODE    TYPE1   TYPE2   TYPE3   AMOUNT
1        XX      YD      RE       22
2        LY      GD      DD       45
3        SD     DFD      WW       75
```

and here is the desired results after i run my query:

```
CODE    GRP_NM  GRP_VALUES      AMT
1         TYPE1   XX            22
2         TYPE1   LY            45
3         TYPE1   SD            75
1         TYPE2   YD            22
2         TYPE2   GD            45
3         TYPE2   DFD           75
1         TYPE3   RE            22
2         TYPE3   DD            45
3         TYPE3   WW            75
```

and here is the query i have but does not give me the results that i need:

```
SELECT CODE, AMT, GRP_NM FROM MY_TABLE
UNPIVOT
(
 MARKS
 FOR (TYPE1, TYPE2,TYPE3)
)U;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the syntax that you want:

```
with my_table as (
      select 1 as code, 'XX' as type1, 'YD' as type2, 'RE' as type3, 22 as amount
  )
select code, grp_num, grp_values, amount
from MY_TABLE
unpivot (grp_values for grp_num in (TYPE1, TYPE2, TYPE3)
        ) U;
```

Personally, I find the `unpivot` syntax quite difficult to remember, so I usually perform this operation using a `cross join` and `case` statements.

Comment: i have more than 20000 rows so running select statement for each value is really not reasonable so i am hoping there is some other solution.  thanks